# calling variable inside function jquery ajax call and returns undefiend

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, variables

i'm newbie on jquery and ajax and i want to ask about my code. i make a form for my app and when i submit my form, it will change the page and getting "id_login" from ajax process.

and my problem is i can't call my variable that i have assigned inside $.ajax, and  it will be displayed on "#info" after i changed the page.but it displayed undefiend not the value. i don't know where the problem of it, and my code is below :

```
var getVar;    
$('#submit').click(function(){
            var u= $("#username").val();
            var p= $("#password").val();
            if (u !="" && p !==""){

                $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'test.php',
                beforeSend: function(x) {
                    if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                        x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                    }
                },
                data:{username:u,password:p},
                async:false,
                global:false,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.success == true){
                        window.localStorage.setItem("id_login",data.session);
                        getVar = window.localStorage.getItem("id_login");//the value is 1
                        $.mobile.changePage('#page1');
                    }
                }

                }); 

            }

        });

            $("#info").append("result:"+getVar);//the result always show undefiend not 1
```

i've been looking for solution of my problem in internet include here about global variable, calling variable inside function ,etc. but it still doesn't work.
so, can anybody tell me the problem, please?
and sorry if my english is bad 
thank you

Comment: The `getVar` is not updated until you click on the element and the ajax request is completed, but you are using it before any of these things happens, so you get the value undefined

Comment: The solution will be is to more the code `$("#info").append("result:"+getVar);` to the ajax success handler

Comment: oh ya, i think it can be update when i click on element.although, i append it outside of function click.but i'm wrong, thank you for your answer. it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data){
                if (data.success == true){
                    window.localStorage.setItem("id_login",data.session);
                    getVar = window.localStorage.getItem("id_login");//the value is 1

                    $("#info").append("result:"+getVar);
                    //this has to run every time you get a 
                    //successful Ajax call and you want
                    //this variable to be printed out correct.
                    $.mobile.changePage('#page1');

                }
```